# Windows Service, proper way to get installation path

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that will be deployed on a few systems. I would like to get the installation path of where the user installed the service. I'm trying to get the installation path so I know where to read custom config files from. What is the proper way of doing this? I tried using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` but returned the full path and executable.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the directory name from the assembly's location:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```